# tiny MCE add font dropdown list

Tags: jquery, tinymce, rte

Can someone please tell me how to add font dropdown list to TinyMCE?

I referred the example in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g51nrhhf/26/

I tried the below code by adding font-family, but didnt work:

```
 toolbar: "InsertTecDocLink | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link  image | font-family "
```

Please suggest!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get any errors? What's the result of using the example you provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example contains the init settings you need:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/classic/

In particular you need to add `fontselect` to a toolbar to get what you want.  The init in your fiddle would then become:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  toolbar: 'fontsizeselect | fontselect',
  fontsize_formats: "8px 10px 12px 14px 18px 24px 36px",
  font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace;'
});
```